# Can the mgconsole history file be disabled?

Tags: memgraphdb

Is it possible to disable mgsconsole history file? At the moment I use simple script and corn job to delete mgconsole history file from time to time. I'd like to disable history for mgconsole. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can disable the history. Start the `mgconosle` with flag `-no_history`.